# A way to pause a method for 1 second

Tags: java, wait

I'm doing a console application with Java. I have one method where I need to wait one second, then continue with my method. It's just a simple method, so it means there is no thread involved. What can I do?

My Program looks like this:

- User writes something
- Program waits 1 second
- Then it does calculation.

It has to wait 1 second!

Comment: `there is no thread involved` I'm not a Java expert, but I'm pretty sure every thing runs on a thread

Comment: There is a thread. There is the main thread running. You are not using **multiple** threads. See Semih Eker's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Try this to pause for 1 second;

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Comment: OP, don't be afraid of the word "Thread" here. This is how you make a simple method wait one second. Just copy-paste.

Comment: I tried it with 5000 miliseconds it was like 0.3 seconds long in reality. Is there a reason why it might not work?

Comment: the other guy, please write your answer, I'm ready to learn better way from you.@user3549340 as I specified in question, sleep method take parameter as milliseconds and for one second you must give 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: @SemihEke, for my own curiosity, in an single threaded application, when might the catch block for InterruptedException be executed? I'm trying to understand why the solution outlined might be superior to, for example, throwing an IllegalStateException.

Comment: I specified common usage of Thread. As you mentioned, in an single threaded application, InterruptedException isn't required, we can use another Exception types.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this

```
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```